# String Conversion python

Tags: python, string, encoding, character-encoding

I have a small question on string conversion in python3.

`s = '\x001\x002\x001\x000\x005\x005\x000\x004\x000\x000\x00'`

print(s) -> gives the output :

`1 2 1 0 5 5 0 4 0 0`

However, when I try to convert the string using the following:

`bytes(s, 'utf16').decode('utf16')` , I get '\x001\x002\x001\x000\x005\x005\x000\x004\x000\x000\x00'.

What is the way to get the same output as print(s) programmatically?

Comment: BTW: the second variant it is wrong. It is not UTF16 (but UTF16BE)

Comment: It seems utf-16 works as well. https://realpython.com/python-encodings-guide/

Comment: Interesting, I wouldn't have expected `'\x00'` to print as a blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On first example, you print the string `s`, and console will ignore the `\x00`. You do a `print(s)`.

On you last line, you get the string from python prompt.  If you print it: `print(bytes(s,'utf-16').decode('utf-16'))`, you get what you want.

So Python prompt show you to the variable, with context (e.g. you see also the `'` signs), but not the real representation of the string (which do you have with `print`).

ADDENDUM:

`print` will print the string in its argument, eventually calling `str()` to convert the argument to string.  But python prompt will print the representation of the variable (given with `repr()`. So you can `print(repr(bytes(s,'utf-16').decode('utf-16')))` to get the same string you get in python interactive session, but as string. Instead of printing, you can assign such function (`r = repr(bytes(...).decode(...))`, so you have `r[0]` is `'`, `r[1]` is `\`, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Giacomo for the answer. I wanted to perform operation on the string that comes on printing it, via print(str(s)). Is there a way to store the print output to a variable or some better way?

Comment: `str(s)` is a no-op if `s` is already a string.  What Python prints at the console if you don't use `print` is actually `repr(s)`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Right. It is a leftover of a draft. I wanted to point `str` with `repr`, but it was also not so useful. I'll edit away the str

Comment: @sk1pro99: I added about how to get the string in the second case. Exact output in first case (but also second case) is difficult, it depends on the console (and font). `\x00` has not meaning in Unicode, so it is not printed, but other control character could be interpreted differently. Then all combining characters (and code points). `repr()` avoid control characters and *difficult* characters by escaping them.. And a warning: Your code may work in Unix/Macos (now Unicode by default), but on Windows you may get different output.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to decode this binary and you will get the answer

```
x = b'\x001\x002\x001\x000\x005\x005\x000\x004\x000\x000\x00'
str1 = x.decode('utf-8')
print(" ".join([i for i in str1 if ord(i) != 0]))
```

Second Solution:

```
x = '1 2 1 0 5 5 0 4 0 0'
str_utf32 = x.encode('utf16')
print("Encoding :",str_utf32)
print("Decoding :",str_utf32.decode('utf16'))
```

output

```
Encoding : b'\xff\xfe1\x00 \x002\x00 \x001\x00 \x000\x00 \x005\x00 \x005\x00 \x000\x00 \x004\x00 \x000\x00 \x000\x00'
Decoding : 1 2 1 0 5 5 0 4 0 0
```

Comment: How to you suggest to get s to x? x = bytes(s, 'utf-8'). If I then do bytes(x, 'utf-8').decode('utf-8'), I get the same string '\x001\x002\x001\x000\x005\x005\x000\x004\x000\x000\x00'. Although if I use print, I get the converted string.